# Using variables in BigQuery DDL with external GCS bucket

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Using BigQuery data definition language and standard SQL only, is it possible to use current date as a variable to use it as a `gs://` path in the following query ?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE staging.my_table
OPTIONS (
  format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
  uris = ['gs://bucket/path/to/logs/2020-10-08/*.jsonl']
)
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: `DECLARE foo STRING DEFAULT '2020-10-28';

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE staging.my_table OPTIONS (format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON', uris = ['gs://bucket/path/to/logs/@foo/*.jsonl'])`
drops an error saying the bucket doesn't exist

Comment: And what you've got?

Comment: "Invalid value: Error while reading table: my_table, error message: The table my_table cannot be read because uris did not match any data. at [3:1]" and hardcoding the date works of course.

Comment: have you tried `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`? should work!

Comment: Indeed thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
  CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE staging.my_table
  OPTIONS (
    format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    uris = ['gs://bucket/path/to/%s/*.jsonl']
  )
""", CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS STRING));
```

The best practice is to use [Hive partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs) on GCS though